# Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed SQL Server for update sys.foreign_keys

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Foreign_keys (in view)

I can not update row cell `is_not_for_replication`. I searched on this site and I use any script code but it did not work!

i need to add NOT FOR REPLICATION to all FOREIGN KEY

[image]

this script make alter table but i can not excute generate codes

```
USE Test1;
GO
SELECT
  Drop_FK = 'ALTER TABLE [' + FK.FKTableSchema +'].[' + FK.FKTableName + '] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + FK.FKName + ']; ',
  Add_FK_NFR = 'ALTER TABLE [' + FK.FKTableSchema +
    '].[' + FK.FKTableName +
    '] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [' + FK.FKName +
    '] FOREIGN KEY([' + FK.FKTableColumn +
    ']) REFERENCES [' + schema_name(sys.objects.schema_id) +
    '].[' + sys.objects.[name] + ']([' + sys.columns.[name] +
    ']) NOT FOR REPLICATION; '
FROM sys.objects
INNER JOIN sys.columns
  ON (sys.columns.[object_id] = sys.objects.[object_id])
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    sys.foreign_keys.[name] AS FKName,
    schema_name(sys.objects.schema_id) AS FKTableSchema,
    sys.objects.[name] AS FKTableName,
    sys.columns.[name] AS FKTableColumn,
    sys.foreign_keys.referenced_object_id AS referenced_object_id,
    sys.foreign_key_columns.referenced_column_id AS referenced_column_id
  FROM sys.foreign_keys
  INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns
    ON (sys.foreign_key_columns.constraint_object_id = sys.foreign_keys.[object_id])
  INNER JOIN sys.objects
    ON (sys.objects.[object_id] = sys.foreign_keys.parent_object_id)
  INNER JOIN sys.columns
    ON (sys.columns.[object_id] = sys.objects.[object_id])
      AND (sys.columns.column_id = sys.foreign_key_columns.parent_column_id)
) FK
  ON (FK.referenced_object_id = sys.objects.[object_id])
    AND (FK.referenced_column_id = sys.columns.column_id)
WHERE (sys.objects.[type] = 'U')
  AND (sys.objects.is_ms_shipped = 0)
  AND (sys.objects.[name] NOT IN ('sysdiagrams'))
```

u can run this code for any database

Comment: Just as intended. Use DDL to modify!

Comment: Why are you even *trying* to do this..?

Comment: The `sys` objects are **system-internal catalog view** - and both **system-internal** and **view** should make it clear that those are **read-only** by design - and that's a **good** thing! (tm)

Comment: i need add  NOT FOR REPLICATION  to all FOREIGN KEY.